# How to get response of getEmailIdentity Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-sesv2

I am using the [getEmailIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-sesv2-2019-09-27.html#getemailidentity) SDK function of Amazon SES (V2), Here in the docs they have provided response but when I am using that, getting no response.

```php
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\SesV2\SesV2Client;
try {
     $data = [
      'region' => 'ap-south-1',
      'version' => 'latest',
     ];
     $data['credentials'] = array(
       'key'     => 'OIUUxyz',
       'secret'  => '78stxyz',
     );
    return $amzone_ses = new SesV2Client($data);
  } catch (AwsException $e) {
    throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
  }
```

```php
try {
            $sesClient = $this->getSESClient();
            // Retrieve the object
            $result = $sesClient->getEmailIdentity([
                'EmailIdentity' => 'rathor.in', // REQUIRED
            ]);
            if ($result) {
                return ['success'=> true, 'message' =>"Domain successfully found.", 'response' =>$result];
            }
            return ['success'=> true, 'message' =>"No domain found!"];
        } catch (AwsException $e) {
            return ['success'=> false, 'message' =>$e->getMessage()];
        }
```

Can anyone help me here why I am getting different result?

thanks